# Java ProcessExplorer is there a way to allow a remote machine to handle the process run?

Tags: java, tomcat, java-11, processbuilder, remote-desktop

working on a problem where ProcessBuilder is being used to start a batch file on a remote machine.  However I wan't to have the ability to either wait for the processes completion or not. When waiting everything works perfectly, however when not waiting the process never actually finishes on the remote machine.  I believe this is because I am returning immediately after starting the process and this is causing a hang (process which should take 1 second to 1 minutes is running for 15 minutes before finally closing).  Is there a way I can get the process to finish and not have to wait for it to complete? Any help would be appreciated.

```
        Path batchFile = pathService.getFilePath(login.getNode(), "run.bat");

        // When file does not exists there is no point in executing it
        if (!Files.exists(batchFile)) {
            return;
        }

        try {
            // Run batch file
            Process process = new ProcessBuilder(ImmutableList.of(
                            "cmd",
                            "/c",
                            batchFile.toString()))
                    .directory(pathService.getRootPath(login.getNode()).toFile())
                    .redirectErrorStream(true)
                    .start();

            if (!waitForCompletion) {
                return;
            }

            String standardOutput = collectString(process.getInputStream());
            String standardError = collectString(process.getErrorStream());

            if (!process.waitFor(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
                LOGGER.warn("Process '{}' is hanging with output '{}' and error '{}'", batchFile.toString(), standardOutput, standardError);
            }
        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Note the warnings of the [Process](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Process.html) javadoc:

> Because some native platforms only provide limited buffer size for
> standard input and output streams, failure to promptly write the input
> stream or read the output stream of the process may cause the process
> to block, or even deadlock.

When you exit your method early with `if (!waitForCompletion)` then you skip consuming stdout. If your sub-process is writing a lot of output to stdout then it will block if stdout buffer is filled => process freezes.

If that is the case, you can avoid the issue by one of:

1. Add `.inheritIO()` when `ProcessBuilder` to ensure output is passed onto default for current Java process
2. Send STDOUT/ERR to a file instead, adding `.redirectInput(new File("somefile.log"))`
3. Add a background task to consume stdout, something like this but with suitable try/catch in the `Runnable` for you to deal with `IOException` / logging etc:

   ```
    if (!waitForCompletion) {
        // Ensure STDOUT is consumed
        new Thread(() -> collectString(process.getInputStream())).start();
    }
   ```

Comment: #3 here works fine for the parent process but it does not work for any process that the parent process calls if the parent process finishes before the child process does. I wasn't trying to duplicate my question, I am trying to fix an issue and understand a language and tech that I have never worked with before.

Comment: Its not clear what you mean - its worth editing your other question. If your script uses "start other.bat" the other script is run in new cmd process. But as you say you use "call other.bat" the parent continues after the call - unless other.bat has "exit" instead of "exit /B"